# Generate DOM content only for specific key's in JSON using handlebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebar js for templating. If i want the handlebar to generate dom content only for keys 2,3  or 1,2,3 from the json data how can i do it ?

**JSON structure**

```
{
"items": {
    "1": {
        "title": "Title1",
        "date": "2/16/2012"
    },
    "2": {
        "title": "Title2",
        "date": "2/16/2012"
    },
    "3": {
        "title": "Title3",
        "date": "2/16/2012"
    },
    "4": {
        "title": "Title4",
        "date": "2/16/2012"
    }
}
}
```

HTML should have data as shown below

```
<li> data of item2 </li>
<li> data of item3 </li>
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, this

```
var DOMCreationKeys = [2,3];
var k=0;

var updatedJSON = {
"items": {}};

for (item in myjson_data.items){
    if(item == DOMCreationKeys [k++]){
        updatedJSON["items"].push(myjson_data.items[item]);
}

contnr.append(list_tmpl(updatedJSON ));
```

Should work :)

Comment: thanks for the reply but how will handlebar interpret this? because it takes JSON data for input , so i should be sending it an object with data of only 2,3. In JS i'm sending the json object like this .. contnr.append(list_tmpl(myjson_data));

Comment: what is myjson_data? Is it individual object from JSON or collection of objects from JSON?

Comment: it is a collection of objects .. basically whole items. So instead of that i want to send data of only items 2,3 to handlebars so that it can create dom

Comment: In this line updatedJSON[items].push(myjson_data.items[item]); i get [items] is undefined.

Comment: for some reason  using $.extend shows only the last added item.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15512/discussion-between-aditya-parab-and-user1184100)